# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection when implementing session state unit tests in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have written the following tests for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters` as I am migrating an ASP.NET application to .NET Core.

How can I use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in my tests?

Here is the test class;

```
[TestClass]
public class HttpSessionStateTests
{
    private readonly Fixture _fixture;

    public HttpSessionStateTests()
    {
        // generate anonymous test data
        _fixture = new Fixture();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SetupSessionID_WhenRetrieved_ShouldReturnTheSameSessionID()
    {
        // Arrange
        var id = _fixture.Create<string>();

        var session = new Mock<ISessionState>();
        session.Setup(s => s.SessionID).Returns(id);

        var state = new HttpSessionState(session.Object);

        // Act
        var result = state.SessionID;

        // Assert
        result.Should().Be(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: So far so good.  What's wrong with it? You didn't share the results.

Comment: What's your `Fixture` ?  Besides, you can read [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more ?

Comment: @QingGuo Fixture is part of AutoFixture open source library. The Fixture object is used to generate anonymous test data and greatly simplify the arrange phase.